# EF Core cascade deleting not working on 1:1 relationship

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, .net-5

In this example I have two entities, `Place`, and `Person`. When I delete a `Person` I want `person.Home` to be deleted. Whilst only `Person` is using the `Place` entity at the moment, it is likely that more entities will be created in the future that also use Place, so I don't want to have `place.OwnerPerson` or anything similar.

I wanted to use cascade deleting to implement this, so I've added

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Home)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Person>(e => e.HomeId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

to try and achieve that.

According to DB Browser for SQLite, this generates a table with the create command

```
CREATE TABLE "People" (
    "Id" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_People" PRIMARY KEY,
    "Name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "HomeId" TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_People_Places_HomeId" FOREIGN KEY ("HomeId") REFERENCES "Places" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

which I think looks right.

However, when I delete a `Person` from the context, the `Place` that was their `person.Home` still exists.

In the MCVE below, I was expecting the output:

```
People:
    Fiona

Places:
    Castle


People:

Places:
```

but I actually get

```
People:
    Fiona

Places:
    Castle


People:

Places:
    Castle
```

---

**MCVE**

```
// Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -Version 5.0.15

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace CascadeDeleteMcve
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Guid id = SetUpDb();
            PrintDetails();
            TestDelete(id);
            PrintDetails();
        }

        private static Guid SetUpDb()
        {
            DemoContext context = new();
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            Place castle = new()
            {
                Name = "Castle",
            };

            Person fiona = new()
            {
                Name = "Fiona",
                Home = castle,
            };

            context.People.Add(fiona);
            context.Places.Add(castle);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return fiona.Id;
        }

        private static void TestDelete(Guid id)
        {
            DemoContext context = new();
            Person fiona = context.People.First(person => person.Id == id);
            context.People.Remove(fiona);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private static void PrintDetails()
        {
            DemoContext context = new();

            Console.WriteLine("People:");
            foreach (Person person in context.People)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{person}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Places:");
            foreach (Place place in context.Places)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t{place}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public class DemoContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=data.db;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Home)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Person>(e => e.HomeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }

    public class Place
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Guid HomeId { get; set; }

        public Place Home { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

*Note, I am restricted to using .NET 5*

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite you are supposed to use `foreign keys=true` in your connection string to enable ForeignKeys constraint since they are disabled by default.

Link to SqlLite documentation about this issue:
https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: `Data Source=data.db;foreign keys=true;` has no effect unfortunately